# How can I select all categories in WordPress using a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How can I select all categories in WordPress using a MySQL query?

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT term_id as id, name as post_title, slug as post_url 
    FROM $wpdb->terms ORDER BY name
```

but it returns tags also.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT t.term_id AS id,
       t.name    AS post_title,
       t.slug    AS post_url
FROM   wp_terms t
       LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
              ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
WHERE  tt.taxonomy = 'category'
ORDER  BY name
```